# Binary to ASM instruction conversion question

Tags: assembly, disassembly, lc3

I have this binary number `0000000001101100` that I am trying to convert to an LC-3 assembler instruction. What I came up with was "`BR 0x6C`" for the instruction does this seem right?

Comment: seems right....what happens if you simulate it?

Comment: Here is a good explanation: http://faculty.lasierra.edu/~ehwang/courses/cptg245/LC3/LC-3%20Instructions.pdf